# Como varrer um array de objetos e retornar seus valores em uma string

Tags: javascript, array

Eu tenho esse vetor de objetos aqui:

```js
var usuarios = [
 {
 nome: "Diego",
 habilidades: ["Javascript", "ReactJS", "Redux"]
 },
 {
 nome: "Gabriel",
 habilidades: ["VueJS", "Ruby on Rails", "Elixir"]
 }
];
```

e preciso retornar isso:

```js
O Diego possui as habilidades: Javascript, ReactJS, Redux
O Gabriel possui as habilidades: VueJS, Ruby on Rails, Elixir
```

Como fazer?

Comment: Já tentou o uso de foreach`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com um simples `for...of` você lê a array e seus objetos:

```js
var usuarios = [
 {
 nome: "Diego",
 habilidades: ["Javascript", "ReactJS", "Redux"]
 },
 {
 nome: "Gabriel",
 habilidades: ["VueJS", "Ruby on Rails", "Elixir"]
 }
];

for(let u of usuarios){
   console.log("O "+ u.nome +" possui as habilidades: "+ u.habilidades.join(", "));
}
```

No caso da array `habilidades`, usei um `.join()` para separar os itens com uma vírgula e espaço.

Comment: +1, muito boa resposta, só não entendi pq foi fechada.

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou, obrigado. Também dá pra fazer usando template strings, usando o E6.

Comment: @DanúbioVieiraLima Dá pra usar template strings tb. Abs!

Answer (score 2):

Com o jquery você pode usar o $.each com o join do array

Isso se você pretender usar em alguma página

Segue exemplo:

```js
var usuarios = [
 {
 nome: "Diego",
 habilidades: ["Javascript", "ReactJS", "Redux"]
 },
 {
 nome: "Gabriel",
 habilidades: ["VueJS", "Ruby on Rails", "Elixir"]
 }
];

const percorrer = () =>{
  var texts = ''
  $.each(usuarios, (i, j) => {
    texts += `<p><strong>${j.nome}</strong> possui as seguintes habilidades: ${j.habilidades.join()}</p>`
  })
  
  $('.content').html( texts )
}

$(()=>{
  percorrer()
})
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="content">
</div>
```